# Why is the interface builder action for tap gesture recognizer in iOS not fire?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder, uitapgesturerecognizer

In iOS in Xcode, I dropped a tap gesture recognizer control onto a label, and control-dragged the tap gesture recognizer to create an interface builder action. When I tap the label, the interface builder action doesn't fire. Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func actionTapLabelInstrumentDropDown(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    print("actionTapLabelInstrumentDropDown")

    instrumentDropDown.show()

}
```

The print statement never prints.

Comment: Labels don't response to user interactions by default. You need to enable user interactions on the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing an answer based on **@rmaddy** observations in comments under the question, just so it would be more visible to the community.

> Labels don't response to user interactions by default. You need to enable user interactions on the label.

---

Adding my two cents:

If your `UILabel` is in Storyboard/NIB, you only need to check `User Interaction Enabled` checkbox in the right side menu.

If you are programmatically creating `UILabel` then you will need to call following function in order to enable it:

```
self.myLabel.userInteractionEnabled = true
```